# How to graph population age structure by sex using GoogleVis and R?

Tags: r, googlevis

Am trying to create a graph of population structure by age and sex using R and googleVis. However the graph never fully loads on the browser I just get a "loading" message and no output. The command am using in RStudio is

```
plot(gvisMotionChart(data, idvar = "id", timevar = "ExpYear", xvar = "ExpYear", yvar = "n", colorvar = "AgeGroup",sizevar = "n"))
```

My data My data basically shows the number of people in a particular age bracket (AgeGroup column) in a particular year (between 2000-2014) for a particular gender and can be found here: `https://github.com/kilimba/data`.

Am not sure how to go about debugging, or whether it is even a problem with the code or data. Am also new to bot R and GoogleVis so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Tumaini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same variable for `timevar` and `xvar` dimension.

Try for example (time = year, x = AgeGroup, y = n and color = sex):

```
plot(gvisMotionChart(data, idvar = "id", timevar = "ExpYear", xvar = "AgeGroup", yvar = "n", colorvar = "Sex"))
```

To see the motion you have to restructure your data so that you have one ID for all years. Set ID for example as combination of AgeGroup and Sex:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- data %>%
  group_by(ExpYear, AgeGroup, Sex ) %>%
  summarize(n = sum(n)) %>%
  mutate(id = paste(AgeGroup, Sex))
```

And plot with:

```
plot(gvisMotionChart(df2, idvar = "id", timevar = "ExpYear", xvar = "AgeGroup", yvar = "n", colorvar = "Sex"))
```

Comment: Well , with the above suggestion something does come up, however the motion chart has no motion....clicking on the play button shows none of the transitions over the years

Comment: The problem is with id: for example id=3 is only defined for 2001. See answer update